# Routing between react and ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core, react-router, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a task where I have to fix errors and create some new functionality. I have been struggling with routing between react and ASP.NET Core.

My endpoints in the startup file look like this

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
            });
```

Some methods from the controller look like this:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class FileController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<FileController> _logger;
        private readonly IFileRepository _fileRepository;

        public FileController(ILogger<FileController> logger, IFileRepository fileRepository)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _fileRepository = fileRepository;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public Task<List<FileDetails>> Get()
        {
            return _fileRepository.GetFileDetailsAsync();
        }


[HttpGet]
public async Task<FileDetails> GetDetailedFileView(int id)
{
    FileDetails fileDetails = new FileDetails();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id.ToString()))
    {
        fileDetails = await _fileRepository.GetDetailedFileView(id);
    }

    return fileDetails;
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(FileDetails fileDetails)
{
    if (fileDetails is Object)
    {
        fileDetails = await _fileRepository.DeleteFileDetailsAsync(fileDetails);
    }

    return (IActionResult)fileDetails;
}
```

and  in react it looks like

```
<Route path='/file-list' component={FileList} />
```

It works only if I use

```
[HttpGet]
public Task<List<FileDetails>> Get()
{
    return _fileRepository.GetFileDetailsAsync();
}
```

but from what I gather only Task Action/IAction methods should be in the controller?

I have been searching for hours and still can't wrap my head around how to properly route this app from backend perhaps and avoid routing in react or make it match otherwise it errors out because json can't be built or the wrong path has been assigned. Please help.

Comment: As long as you're not going to return status codes like forbidden or bad request, it is OK to return `Task<List<FileDetails>>`.

Comment: @RoarS. can I literally do that for all methods in the controller or would that be considered bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

**Path to controller**
As you have `[Route("[controller]")]` and controller is called `FileController` your current path to controller is `/file`
If you need API to be called by different path like `/file-list` you can set it by changing to `[Route("/file-list")]`

**Get by id**
If you want to get a specific record by requesting to `/file/5` add a `[Route("{id:int}"]` to GetDetailedFileView like this

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id:int}"]
public async Task<FileDetails> GetDetailedFileView(int id)
{
    FileDetails fileDetails = new FileDetails();

    fileDetails = await _fileRepository.GetDetailedFileView(id);

    return fileDetails;
}
```

**Delete**
Use `[HttpDelete]` instead of `[HttpGet]` to make actions on DELETE HTTP verb

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(FileDetails fileDetails)
{
    if (fileDetails is Object)
    {
        fileDetails = await _fileRepository.DeleteFileDetailsAsync(fileDetails);
    }

    return (IActionResult)fileDetails;
}
```